# Antlr: getting the class context from a CSharp source file

Tags: antlr4, antlr4cs

I'm trying to use Antlr to parse C# source files. Started with the grammar files that I got from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp, and was able to get the auto-generate CS files. I'm trying to parse a simple class definition, but keep getting an error "line 4:0 mismatched input '' expecting '{'" at the line that reads "var context = parser.class_body();". My intention is to get the class context, pass it to the Visitor, then walk the parse tree of the class. Does someone spot an issue with the code below?

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            text.AppendLine("class Boo{");
            text.AppendLine("");
            text.AppendLine("}");

            AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(text.ToString());
            CSharpLexer lexer = new CSharpLexer(inputStream);
            CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            CSharpParser parser = new CSharpParser(commonTokenStream);

            var c = parser.BuildParseTree;
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()); // true

            //var context = parser.class_base(); // line 1:0 mismatched input 'class' expecting ':'
            var context = parser.class_body(); // line 4:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '{'
            var visitor = new CSharpParserBaseVisitor<object>();
            visitor.VisitClass_body(context);
            // ...

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clearly the entry point is `compilation_unit` if you read the grammar file. Also note that this grammar file is for C# 6 only.

Comment: There are two ways to get the entry point in an Antlr grammars-v4 grammar. (1) In pom.xml, and find the `/project/build/plugins/plugin/configuration/entryPoint` element. The build looks at the pom to determine where to start the parse. (2) In the parser  .g4 file and find the rule with the EOF `//parserRuleSpec[ruleBlock//TOKEN_REF/text()="EOF"]`. If you need an entry point for anything other than `compilation_unit`, you should augment the rule with an EOF like `compilation_unit`. If you need to find the `class_definition`, parse as `compilation_unit`, then find the node using a visitor.